# Scala-lift application connection issue with mongoDB

Tags: scala, lift

Initailly when i connect my scala -lift application to mongodb then it gets connected properly but after sometime if i don't click anywhere on the site and then refresh it then I am getting the below exception but after refreshing again it works fine. So is there any connection timeout issue.. Please guide..

Below are the main points noted from the exception message :

```
Caught and thrown by:
Message: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : widmore.mongohq.com/168.62.177.219:10000/ydpprodtest
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:227)
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)


// Exception message        

Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

MongoDB Exception probably for executing the query showing time of failure . This time sometimes  shows 125 sometimes it is 326 ms etc and varies from page to page

```
Message: com.foursquare.rogue.RogueException: Mongo query on MongoIdentifier(test) [db.users.find({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507ec700e4b086592e6a78fb"}})] failed after 125 ms
```

Thanks

Comment: how did you end up solving the issue?